# Two field multiple values

Tags: entities

Not sure if this is the correct terminology to explain my question, but I have a client on Drupal 7. My client organization is related to another organization that possibly has a Drupal 8 site. There is a content type that is very similar to both organizations, but the other organization has what seems to be a field group of two fields that allows for multiples in the group, as opposed to the fields. I have used field grouping quite frequently in Drupal 7, but can I duplicate that function?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module would fit your needs perfectly, however that doesn't have a Drupal 8 version yet so it's hard to know what the Drupal 8 site is using to do this.

For Drupal 8 there is a [sandbox version of the field collection module](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/larowlan/1966232) however I'm not sure how stable it is.

Another possibility is that they have created a custom field for their site that is a combination of multiple elements.

If you want any sort of compatibility with the two sites' data the I would suggest asking them how they have implemented theirs and use that option for your Drupal 7 site.

Comment: It looks like an important caveat here is that field collection doesn't seem to be able to be used with previously existing fields. I was trying to relate the interface to the way field groups work (after the fields are created) but it seems that these would need to be new fields.

Comment: You can reuse the same fields but you can't keep the data because it would be a new field instance.
What you would need to do is either export the data, create the new fields then import the data into those fields or create the new instance and then write some SQL to move the content to the new field. The latter option should be fairly trivial. I don't think you'll find a solution that won't have this same issue.